# Assigning a negative value to the DataLabel.Orientation property in Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've written the below code to create an XY scatter chart and format the points to create a visual timeline of events/decisions.

```
Sub UpdateDecisionTimelineChart()

    Dim scount As Integer
    Dim labelrotation As Integer
    Dim c As Range

    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("chtDecisionTimeline").Activate
    scount = 0
        For Each c In Range(Worksheets("Decision Record").Range("C7"), Worksheets("Decision Record").Range("C7").End(xlDown))
        scount = scount + 1
        ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
        With ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(scount)
            .Name = "='Decision Record'!" & c.Offset(0, 1).Address
            .XValues = "='Decision Record'!" & c.Address
            .Values = "='Decision Record'!" & c.Offset(0, -1).Address
            .MarkerStyle = 8
            .MarkerSize = 7
            .MarkerBackgroundColor = RGB(228, 10, 56)
            .MarkerForegroundColor = -2
            .Format.Line.Visible = False
            .ApplyDataLabels
            .DataLabels.ShowValue = False
            .DataLabels.ShowSeriesName = True
            .DataLabels.Position = xlLabelPositionAbove
            .DataLabels.Orientation = -45
        End With
        Next
End Sub
```

The data which I am using is set out as follows:

[image: Range Example]

And the resultant timeline looks like this:

[image]

The code works fine (although I know it's not pretty) except for the bit where I try to assign a value of `-45` to the `.DataLabels.Orientation` property; this actually sets a value of `45`.

MSDN states: 'The value of this property can be set to an integer value from –90 to 90 degrees or to one of the following constants.', but any negative integer value I assign converts to a positive value.

Is it possible to assign a negative value to the `.DataLabels.Orientation` property and, if so, how?

Comment: What happens if you set `.DataLabels.Orientation = 45`?

Comment: Wow Axel! That was much easier than expected. Can you explain why that works?

Comment: "Can you explain why that works?" No, I can't. Was just try and error. Seems as if VBA has the degrees exact inversely the Excel GUI.